# rancher 2 in private network how to expose a service?

Tags: rancher

So I am building my knowledge on rancher/kubernetes and I am testing some workload. My current home setup looks like this:

/internet/ -- | pfsense (dns + fw) | -- rancher node1 (cluster: etcd, worker, control) -- rancher node 2 (wroker).

I have deloyed the simple web server docker image from docker hub and it's running. Now I want this web page to be available into my internal network )so in my internal network). I know that I can expose the 80 port of this worload into the node so I can access it using 192.168.1.x:80. But let say that the worload move to the other worker, the ip will not be the same. So how can I expose this service and use my internal dns to always go the the right ip? Do you have an idea on how to acheive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new "Load Balancer" entry with a specific hostname you want to use. This assumes, the internal nodes can query the local DNS server and get the right reply.

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Edit 1:
Forgot to mention that you need to point the external DNS server to the worker node IP address.

yourinternaldns.example.com -> worker node IP address(es)

In many of the real deployments, I have seen usage of an external loadbalancer pointing to multiple worker nodes using the DNS name.

Comment: Thanks! Ok but on which ip should the hostname resolve to? I have checked that my web docker image was able to resolve against my internal dns and it's fine.

Comment: Added more info. Let me know if you still have more questions.

Comment: What If I have multiple workers? Each running an ingress-controller by default by rancher

Comment: @LeonardoChaia you can point your external LB to point at all the node/worker IP addresses.

Comment: I'm on bare-metals. This menas I need to host an LB outside the cluster? how do you handle new nodes being added afterwards? got any article on this topic? Thanks Leo.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but heard about metallb. https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/kubernetes-metal-lb-for-on-prem-baremetal-cluster-in-10-minutes-c2eaeb3fe813

Comment: Came back to say that MetalLB works like a charm :) thanks @leodotcloud

Comment: @LeonardoChaia Glad to hear that! Do you mind sharing your experience in a blog post? I think it would be useful for a lot of folks.

Comment: I actually have to create a new production cluster soon and might get the time to write something about baremetals, when and if I do will link it here.